# Map sitecore 8 general link field from Index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I am using sitecore content search API to get the general link field from sitecore index.
Below is my model

```
public class GrantItem : BaseSearchItem
{
    [IndexField("grant_name")]
    public string GrantName { get; set; }

    [IndexField("grant_description")]
    public string GrantDescription { get; set; }

    [IndexField("grant_categories_sm")]
    public CategoryItem[] GrantCategories { get; set; }

    [IndexField("grant_status_s")]
    public CategoryItem GrantStatus { get; set; }

    [IndexField("grant_application_type_sm")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldIDValueConverter))]
    public IEnumerable<ID> ApplicationType { get; set; }

    [IndexField("grant_url")]
    public string GrantURL { get; set; }
}
```

When I am using sitecore content search API. I am getting the following xml in the GrantURL.

```
 <link linktype=\"external\" url=\"http://www.google.com.au\" anchor=\"\"    
 target=\"\" />
```

Is there any default converter in sitecore to map this to a Link field or do I need to parse it manually or create a custom converter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware there no type converters for this.

It's quite easy to create your own though. This blog post has code that worked for me and you just have to implement the ConvertFrom and ConvertTo methods

http://reasoncodeexample.com/2014/01/30/indexing-datetime-fields-sitecore-7-content-search/

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var resultItem in Model.SearchRequest.SearchResults)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    @{
                                        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                                        doc.LoadXml(resultItem.CrossSiteUrl);
                                        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
                                        string path = String.Empty;
                                        string target = String.Empty;
                                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultItem.CrossSiteUrl))
                                        {
                                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(root.Attributes["url"].Value))
                                            {
                                                path = root.Attributes["url"].Value;
                                            }
                                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(root.Attributes["target"].Value))
                                            {
                                                target = root.Attributes["target"].Value;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    <td><a href="@path" target="@target">@resultItem.PageTitle</a></td>
                                    <td>@resultItem.DownloadTypeName</td>
                                    <td>@resultItem.ReleaseDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                                    <td>@Convert.ToInt64(resultItem.FileSize).ConvertToSize()</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4">@resultItem.ShortDescription</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
```

Comment: You can use the above snippet. I was having the same problem in my view where I have downloads section. We have migrated from Lucene to Solr and getting this issue with the indexing. Probably it will be useful for someone trying to read the URL field.

Comment: The XML script below handles the URL getting from the XML. 
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.LoadXml(resultItem.CrossSiteUrl);
                        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
   String path = root.Attributes["url"].Value;