# How to index general link field

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I would like to know how Solr indexes general link field or do we need to create computed index field for this ?

I have a helper class which is inheriting from SearchResultItem and it has below index field.

```
    [IndexField("Call To Action")]

    public LinkField CallToAction { get; set; }
```

This field is a general link field in sitecore.

Below is the search code which retrieves all the Event_card values except CallToAction (i.e. Always null). if I convert the field type from Link to string , I get the entire general link raw value which is difficult to parse at view and make it editable through glass mapper.

if (result.TotalSearchResults != 0)

```
            {

                //Load Event card data to be displayed on page

                var resultItems =

                    result.Select(c => new Event_Card

                    {

                        Headline = c.Document.Headline,

                        Start_Date=c.Document.StartDate,

                        Content=c.Document.ContentData,

                        Call_To_Action=c.Document.CallToAction  // this is always null                 

                    });

            }
```

Here is my  Entity class related to Event_Card

Event_Card

[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Team Development for Sitecore - GlassItem.tt", "1.0")]

```
    [SitecoreField(IEvent_CardConstants.Call_To_ActionFieldName)] 



    public virtual Link Call_To_Action { get; set; }
```

IEvent_Card

[SitecoreField(IEvent_CardConstants.Call_To_ActionFieldName)]

```
    Link Call_To_Action { get; set; }
```

public static partial class IEvent_CardConstants

```
{
```

public static readonly ID Call_To_ActionFieldId = new ID("4c296a05-d05f-47c5-8934-8801bec5be85");

```
    public const string Call_To_ActionFieldName = "Call To Action";
```

}

Can anybody let me know How can I achieve this. If we need to use computed field , an example would be of great help.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map sitecore 8 general link field from Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264224/map-sitecore-8-general-link-field-from-index)

Answer (score -1):

I just quickly browsed and found useful link for you.

[Map sitecore 8 general link field from Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264224/map-sitecore-8-general-link-field-from-index)

I think this Stack overflow question describes what you are saying and there is a link which might be helpful to you.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question.*